# Table Header and table body column mismatch

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a bootstrap table where rows will be added dynamically. But there is an mismatch in table body and table header alignment as shown in snippet below.

```js
function display() {


  var tableRef = document.getElementById('myTable1').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
  var rowsAdd = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length);

  //    var m = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD h:mm a');

  var newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
  newCell.innerHTML = "<input type='text'  form ='form1'  class= 'form-control input-sm' value=' ' id = 'typeofdr' name= 'typeofdr'  required>";
  newCell.style.width = '100px';

  newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
  newCell.innerHTML = "<tr><td><input  form ='form1' class= 'form-control input-sm' value=' '  type='text' id = 'drugname' name= 'drugname'  required> </td></tr>";
  newCell.style.width = '100px';

  newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
  newCell.innerHTML = "<tr><td><input  form ='form1' class= 'form-control input-sm' value=' ' type='text' id = 'strdrug' name= 'strdrug'  required> </td></tr>";
  newCell.style.width = '100px';

  newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
  newCell.innerHTML = "<tr><td><input  form ='form1' class= 'form-control input-sm' value=' ' type='text' id = 'dosage' name= 'dosage'  required> </td></tr>";
  newCell.style.width = '50px';

  newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
  newCell.innerHTML = "<tr><td><input  form ='form1' class= ''  type='checkbox' id = 'dm' value= 'on' name= 'dm'  ><input type='hidden' name='dm' value='off' form='form1'> </td></tr>";
  newCell.style.width = '37.5px';

  newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
  newCell.innerHTML = "<tr><td><input  form ='form1' class= ''  type='checkbox' id = 'da' name= 'da' value='on'  ><input type='hidden' name='da' value='off' form='form1'> </td></tr>";
  newCell.style.width = '37.5px';

  newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
  newCell.innerHTML = "<tr><td><input  form ='form1' class= ''  type='checkbox' id = 'de' name= 'de' value='on' ><input type='hidden' name='de' value='off' form='form1'> </td></tr>";
  newCell.style.width = '37.5px';

  newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
  newCell.innerHTML = "<tr><td><input  form ='form1' class= ''  type='checkbox' id = 'dn' name= 'dn' value='on' ><input type='hidden' name='dn' value='off' form='form1'> </td></tr>";
  newCell.style.width = '37.5px';

  newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
  newCell.innerHTML = "<tr><td><select  form ='form1' class= 'form-control input-sm' value=' ' id = 'baf' name= 'baf'  required><option>Before</option><option>After</option></select> </td></tr>";
  newCell.style.width = '90px';

  newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
  newCell.innerHTML = "<tr><td><input  form ='form1' class= 'form-control input-sm' value=' ' type='text' id = 'totn' name= 'totn'  required> </td></tr>";
  newCell.style.width = '70px';

  newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
  newCell.innerHTML = "<tr><td><input  form ='form1' class= 'form-control input-sm' value=' ' type='text' id = 'nofdays' name= 'nofdays'  required> </td></tr>";
  newCell.style.width = '50px';



  newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
  newCell.innerHTML = "<tr><td class='tds'><i class='fa fa-trash-o' font-size:20px'  onclick='deleteRow(this)'></i></td></tr>";
  newCell.style.width = '50px';



}

function deleteRow(r) {

  var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
  document.getElementById("myTable1").deleteRow(i);


}
```

```css
table.alpha th {
  background-color: #009999;
  color: white;
}

table.alpha .tbalpha {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

table.alpha .thalpha,
.tbalpha {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">




  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive table-hover table-condensed alpha" style="width: 760px; " id="myTable1">
    <thead class="thalpha">
      <tr>
        <th rowspan="2" style="width:100px;">Item</th>
        <th rowspan="2" style="width:100px;">Name of Drug</th>
        <th rowspan="2" style="width:100px;">Strength of Drug</th>
        <th rowspan="2" style="width:50px;">Dosage</th>
        <th colspan="4" style="width:150px;">Frequency</th>
        <th rowspan="2" style="width:90px;">Before /After Food</th>
        <th rowspan="2" style="width:70px;">Total No. of Tablets to be dispensed</th>
        <th rowspan="2" style="width:50px;">No. of Days</th>
        <th rowspan="2" style="width:30px;">Delete Row</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th style="width:37.5px;">M</th>
        <th style="width:37.5px;">A</th>
        <th style="width:37.5px;">E</th>
        <th style="width:37.5px;">N</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody class="tbalpha">


    </tbody>

    <tr id="hide">
      <td><i class='fa fa-plus' style='font-size:20px; color : #ff9900;' onclick="display()"></i></td>
    </tr>

  </table>




</div>
```

As shown in the above snippet,both table column headers and table body column rows are not aligned properly i,e table cells are not exactly below their coressponding header cells. I guess there might be something wrong with the css but if remove display:block in css, table body height gets reduced even though its height is set(in the above css code tbody height set to 200px).

Answer (score 0):

that is because you are altering the way the `tbody` and the `thead` displayed with:

```
table.alpha .thalpha, .tbalpha {
    display: block;
}
```

if you remove it, the columns will be aligned

Comment: Thanks but height of table body gets reduced.Can 't we fix the default height of tbody to some value.

Comment: display block is required to implement scroll on tbody if the height of tbody is more than default height rite?

Comment: if you want a scrollbar, you can use `max-height` on the `tbody`, no need for `display: block`, if you want a certain height when there is no or little rows, you can use `height` instead of `min-height` on the tbody, but the rows would be expanded to the height of `tbody`

Answer (score 0):

You are not suppose to change the `display` property of `tbody` as it has default property of `display: table-row-group`. By removing `display` will align it properly.

```js
function display() {


  var tableRef = document.getElementById('myTable1').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
  var rowsAdd = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length);

  //    var m = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD h:mm a');

  var newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
  newCell.innerHTML = "<input type='text'  form ='form1'  class= 'form-control input-sm' value=' ' id = 'typeofdr' name= 'typeofdr'  required>";
  newCell.style.width = '100px';

  newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
  newCell.innerHTML = "<tr><td><input  form ='form1' class= 'form-control input-sm' value=' '  type='text' id = 'drugname' name= 'drugname'  required> </td></tr>";
  newCell.style.width = '100px';

  newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
  newCell.innerHTML = "<tr><td><input  form ='form1' class= 'form-control input-sm' value=' ' type='text' id = 'strdrug' name= 'strdrug'  required> </td></tr>";
  newCell.style.width = '100px';

  newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
  newCell.innerHTML = "<tr><td><input  form ='form1' class= 'form-control input-sm' value=' ' type='text' id = 'dosage' name= 'dosage'  required> </td></tr>";
  newCell.style.width = '50px';

  newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
  newCell.innerHTML = "<tr><td><input  form ='form1' class= ''  type='checkbox' id = 'dm' value= 'on' name= 'dm'  ><input type='hidden' name='dm' value='off' form='form1'> </td></tr>";
  newCell.style.width = '37.5px';

  newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
  newCell.innerHTML = "<tr><td><input  form ='form1' class= ''  type='checkbox' id = 'da' name= 'da' value='on'  ><input type='hidden' name='da' value='off' form='form1'> </td></tr>";
  newCell.style.width = '37.5px';

  newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
  newCell.innerHTML = "<tr><td><input  form ='form1' class= ''  type='checkbox' id = 'de' name= 'de' value='on' ><input type='hidden' name='de' value='off' form='form1'> </td></tr>";
  newCell.style.width = '37.5px';

  newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
  newCell.innerHTML = "<tr><td><input  form ='form1' class= ''  type='checkbox' id = 'dn' name= 'dn' value='on' ><input type='hidden' name='dn' value='off' form='form1'> </td></tr>";
  newCell.style.width = '37.5px';

  newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
  newCell.innerHTML = "<tr><td><select  form ='form1' class= 'form-control input-sm' value=' ' id = 'baf' name= 'baf'  required><option>Before</option><option>After</option></select> </td></tr>";
  newCell.style.width = '90px';

  newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
  newCell.innerHTML = "<tr><td><input  form ='form1' class= 'form-control input-sm' value=' ' type='text' id = 'totn' name= 'totn'  required> </td></tr>";
  newCell.style.width = '70px';

  newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
  newCell.innerHTML = "<tr><td><input  form ='form1' class= 'form-control input-sm' value=' ' type='text' id = 'nofdays' name= 'nofdays'  required> </td></tr>";
  newCell.style.width = '50px';



  newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
  newCell.innerHTML = "<tr><td class='tds'><i class='fa fa-trash-o' font-size:20px'  onclick='deleteRow(this)'></i></td></tr>";
  //newCell.style.width = '50px';



}

function deleteRow(r) {

  var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
  document.getElementById("myTable1").deleteRow(i);


}
```

```css
table.alpha th {
  background-color: #009999;
  color: white;
}

table.alpha {
  display: block;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">




  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive table-hover table-condensed alpha" style="width: 760px; " id="myTable1">
    <thead class="thalpha">
      <tr>
        <th rowspan="2" style="width:100px;">Item</th>
        <th rowspan="2" style="width:100px;">Name of Drug</th>
        <th rowspan="2" style="width:100px;">Strength of Drug</th>
        <th rowspan="2" style="width:50px;">Dosage</th>
        <th colspan="4" style="width:150px;">Frequency</th>
        <th rowspan="2" style="width:90px;">Before /After Food</th>
        <th rowspan="2" style="width:70px;">Total No. of Tablets to be dispensed</th>
        <th rowspan="2" style="width:50px;">No. of Days</th>
        <th rowspan="2" style="width:30px;">Delete Row</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th style="width:37.5px;">M</th>
        <th style="width:37.5px;">A</th>
        <th style="width:37.5px;">E</th>
        <th style="width:37.5px;">N</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody class="tbalpha">


    </tbody>
    <tr id="hide">
      <td><i class='fa fa-plus' style='font-size:20px; color : #ff9900;' onclick="display()"></i></td>
    </tr>

  </table>

</div>
```

**Note** setting `display: block` to `table` will stretch to 100% `width`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! but cant we set the tbody height to default 200px; I had set it to  200px in css but if we remove table body height gets reduced

Comment: @coder12346 check the updated snippet. you cannot set `display` property on tbody. Here i set `height` and `display`(even this one also not recommended) to `table`. which might give desired output.

Comment: But how to fix the header in same position and provide scroll to only table body?

Answer (score 0):

To fix the header in same position and provide scroll to only table body

```css
    table {
     overflow: auto;
     display: block;
     height: 20vh;
    }

    tr {        
     position: sticky;
     z-index: 1;
     background-color: white;
     top: 0;
    }
```